# Number of Users in Google Analytics seems odd

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using segments to check the number users for a sub-directory. Looking at the number of users per country the data seem odd: from row 4 onward all numbers are divisible by 23. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: This question, as currently written, is not programming related, and would better be suited to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. Nevertheless, you results probably contain sampled data. Could you check that by looking at the green/amber shield on the Analytics UI, at this result?

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably looking at a [sampled](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en) report